# Necessity of API-key in android google-plus auth signup

Tags: android, google-plus

I never had to use a API-key. 
(The most relevant thing I used was a google-generated config json file). 
But in theory I know I should be using a API-key. 
Why is that?

Comment: RTFM ! If you don't use an API key, how does Google APIs know if you're allowed to use their APIs or not ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need an API key to authorize against the API